# Online learning with Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, classification, bayesian

I am trying to predict the inter-arrival time of the incoming network packets. I measure the inter-arrival times of network packets and represent this data in the form of binary features: *xi*= 0,1,1,1,0,... where *xi*=0 if the inter-arrival time is less than a *break-even-time* and 1 otherwise. The data has to be mapped into two possible classes *C={0,1}*, where *C=0* represents a *short* inter-arrival time and 1 represents a *long* inter-arrival time. Since I want to implement the classifier  in an online feature, where as soon as I observe a vector of features *xi*=0,1,1,0..., I calculate the MAP class. Since I don't have a prior estimation of the conditional and prior probabilities, I initialize them as follows:

```
p(x=0|c=0)=p(x=1|c=0)=p(x=0|c=1)=p(x=1|c=1)=0.5
p(c=0)=p(c=1)=0.5
```

For each feature vector *(x1=m1,x2=m2,...,xn=mn)*, when I output a class *C*, I update the conditional and prior probabilities as follows:

```
p(xi=mi|y=c)=a+(1-a)*p(p(xi=mi|c)
p(y=c)=b+(1-b)*p(y=c)
```

The problem is that, I am always getting a biased prediction. Since the number of *long* inter-arrival times are comparatively less than the *short*, the *posterior* of *short* always remains higher than the *long*. Is there any way to improve this? or am I doing something wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a long time series, the best path would probably be to take into account more than a single previous value. the standard way of doing this would be to use a time-window, i.e. split the long vector Xi to overlapping pieces of a constant length, with the last value treated as the class, and use them as the train set. This could be also done on streaming data in an online manner, by incrementally updating the NB model with new data as it arrives.

Note that Using this method, other regression algorithms might end up being a better choice than NB.

Weka (version 3.7.3 and up) has a very nice [dedicated tool](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting+with+Weka) supporting time-series analysis. alternatively, [MOA](http://moa.cs.waikato.ac.nz/) is also based on Weka, and supports modeling of streaming data.

EDIT: it might also be a good idea to move from binary features to the real values (maybe normalized), and apply the threshold post-classification. This might give more information to the regression model (NB or other), allowing better accuracy.

Comment: Could you please provide me some hints about the real values rather than using the binary features. How do I use the real values for the classification? According to your suggestion about splitting the data, if I take a length _n_ of features, at time _k_, I should take _k-n_ features for prediction. When new data arrives, I should, then, take _k-n+1_ to k+1 features. Right?

Comment: regarding using the real values, I suggest using the actual measurement as data points. this is possible if you use regression tools rather than discreet classification. For instance, say your measurements are 4,9,5,7,11,5 ms. instead of defining e.g. 6ms as the border, and transforming the series to 0,1,0,1,1,0 - use the original real values for training and prediction. as for splitting, referring the same example, it can be splitted e.g. to: 4,9,5 -> 7; 9,5,7 -> 11; 5,7,11 -> 5 (format is x1,x2..xk -> expected prediction)

Comment: Thanks for your advise. If I use real values, do I need to maintain the mean and the standard deviation (during online learning)?

Comment: Intuitively, I'd say that if you're using online learning, you're expecting the system to change over time. in that case, I wouldn't suggest constraining the data around fixed points.